# How can we store the log4j messages to a java util list

Tags: java, list, log4j, swt

I want to store the log4j messages to java util list and then fetch the log4j messages from the list . so how can we store the log4j messages to the list.Please help me how can we do this.

Comment: Why Do you want to do this,  the list will undoubtedly fill up your memory to a point it will generate an out of memory exception.  Would it not be better to parse and read the log file?

Comment: I am writing an "application" and not a service.  Thus, the length of a log file is limited by whatever is output for that one invocation of the application, and if the application crashes for out of memory, then the input is simply too large.   In my particular case, the application is a "compiler/linter" and the logfile are the error messages (and the primary output), but I want to use log4j so that the users can configure which messages they want to see.  But they are also stratified in different lists rather than merely time ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the Appender you are using you can for example create this custom Appender that appends the message regularly and also caches it in a list:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyRollingFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {

    private List<LoggingEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        events.add(event);
        super.doAppend(event);
    }

    public synchronized List<LoggingEvent> getEvents() {
        List<LoggingEvent> clone = new ArrayList<>(events);
        events.clear();
        return clone;
    }

}
```

- You can of course override any other Appender you wish and also log or "unlog" the message (event)

Comment: I also need to store the time stamp inside the list when the log message was pushed into the list.So how can we get and push into the list.

Comment: The LoggingEvent class has a 'long getTimeStamp()' method the will return the time the message was logged.